# 401 Unauthorized : Bad Credentials on /login_check

Tags: symfony, jwt, api-platform.com, lexikjwtauthbundle

I am developing an API with Symfony 4.2 and API Platform. I use the Lexik JWT bundle for JWT management.

I started by recovering my project thanks to GIT, then I installed the dependencies. I then configured the database (in the .env). I regenerated the private key and the public key and changed the pass_phrase in the .env (and also in the lexik configuration file).

I created the database, the schema and I also added the fixtures.

.env file :

```
###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=fe2d9e035f82de508cfa67d0ae4720ed
#TRUSTED_PROXIES=127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2
#TRUSTED_HOSTS='^localhost|example\.com$'
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# For an SQLite database, use: "sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
# Configure your db driver and server_version in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:dimitri@localhost:3306/mydb

###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

###> symfony/swiftmailer-bundle ###
# For Gmail as a transport, use: "gmail://username:password@localhost"
# For a generic SMTP server, use: "smtp://localhost:25?encryption=&auth_mode="
# Delivery is disabled by default via "null://localhost"
MAILER_URL=null://localhost
###< symfony/swiftmailer-bundle ###

###> nelmio/cors-bundle ###
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=*
###< nelmio/cors-bundle ###

###> lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle ###
JWT_SECRET_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/private.pem
JWT_PUBLIC_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/public.pem
JWT_PASSPHRASE=dimitri
###< lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle ###

PROJECT_NAME="NAME"
PROJECT_VERSION="1.0"
API_URI="http://127.0.0.1:8000"
```

security.yaml file :

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        login:
            pattern:  ^/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                check_path:               /login_check
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
        api:
            pattern:   ^/
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
        main:
            anonymous: true
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/users/email$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

My project runs locally (on my pc), but when I deploy it on my VPS, I get this response: 401 Unauthorized - Bad credentials

Answer (score 0):

Is that your VPS already configure to support https? From the documentation, you have to add `SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1` in your VirtualHost configuration(if you are using ubuntu server, it will be httpd.conf. I am using one) to support HTTP. if not it will strip away the authorization header.

For more info, refer to this [LeixkJWTAuthentication Documentation](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#installation)

Comment: I added this line in my VHost, but it has no effect (I did a service apache2 restart and service apache2 reload.

My VHost : https://codeshare.io/GqrNxZ